# Replace whole word using ms sql server "replace"

Tags: sql-server

```
declare @str varchar(50)='GoodLuck Markand'
declare @replacedString varchar(50)
set @replacedString = replace(@str,'Good','Better')
print @replacedString
```

I want the output to be unchanged, because there is no single word like 'Good'.
But the output is 'BetterLuck Markand'.

I want the MS SQL Replace function to Compare the exact word and then replace it.
How can i do so?

Comment: It is working just as it should.

Comment: @NoDisplayName. Indeed it is. But I want a functionality to compare the whole word and then replace it.

Comment: Voting to close - this is not how replace works and you show no effort to write a function yourself. Basically you abuse stackoverflow as a code writing service without any effort from your side.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try This: (Works as Expected)

```
declare @str varchar(500)
set @str = 'Good Good Good Good Good Good Good Good Luck Good GoodLuck MarkAndGood GoodMarkAnd MarkAndGood Good'
declare @replacedString varchar(500)
SET @replacedString = replace(@str,' Good ',' Better ')

SET @replacedString = replace(@replacedString,' Good ',' Better ')

SET @replacedString = CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('Good ', @replacedString) = 1 THEN 
                        STUFF(@replacedString, 1, Len('Good'), 'Better')
                      ELSE @replacedString END

SELECT CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(REVERSE(' Good'), REVERSE(@replacedString)) = 1 THEN 
                             Reverse(STUFF(Reverse(@replacedString), CHARINDEX(Reverse(' Good'), 
                             Reverse(@replacedString)), Len(' Good'), Reverse(' Better')))
                      ELSE @replacedString END AS A
```

Input:

**Good Good Luck Good GoodLuck Good**

Result:

**Better Better Luck Better GoodLuck Better**

Comment: Try with this string 'Good GoodLuck Good MarkandGood Good'.

Comment: Try this String 'GoodMarkAnd'. It gives nothing.

Comment: @Kumar, Thanks once again. Here I again fixed the holes. Recheck back.

Answer (score 2):

Append `empty space` at start and end of the string then replace `' Good '` with `' Better '`. Finally use `Ltrim` and  `Rtrim` to remove the empty space at start and end of the string

```
DECLARE @str VARCHAR(50)='Good Luck Good MarkandGood Good'
DECLARE @replacedString VARCHAR(50)

SELECT rtrim(ltrim(Replace(replace(' '+@str+' ',' Good ',' Better '),
' Good ',' Better ')))
```

Comment: I give the input 'Good Good Luck Good MarkandGood Good' and the output I get is 'Better Good Luck Better MarkandGood Better'. Check the second good is not replaced.

Comment: Doesn't handle punctuation at the end of word, like a comma immediately after word, e.g. 'red, white, blue'.

Answer (score 2):

This does not seems to be functionality of Replace, as per MSDN; You have to use give spaces at both side of the word being searched and replaced.

```
replace(@str,' Good ',' Better ')
```

**Replaces all occurrences of a specified string value with another string value.**

Refer [MSDN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862(v=sql.110).aspx)

**Syntax**

```
REPLACE ( string_expression , string_pattern , string_replacement )
```

**Arguments**

string_expression
Is the string expression to be searched. string_expression can be of a character or binary data type.

**string_pattern Is the substring to be found. string_pattern can be of a character or binary data type. 
string_pattern cannot be an empty string (''), and must not exceed the maximum number of bytes that fits on a page.**

string_replacement
Is the replacement string. string_replacement can be of a character or binary data type.

Comment: Good idea but....Unfortunately, in my world, Words are not always surrounded by space. E.g. Start & end of line, comma-separated list.  Other punctuation often follows or precedes a word (e.g. period, comma, semi-colon, exclamation, etc.).