# How to replace a specific word in a sentence without replacing in substring in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I want to replace a specific word in a sentence but not in a substring.

Like

```
DECLARE @i VARCHAR(250)
SET @i = 'MR JOHN NAMR is working from 3 days.'

PRINT REPLACE(@i, 'MR ', '')
```

Output :

```
'JOHN NAis working from 3 days.'
```

Like in this I want to replace 'MR ' with an empty string. But if you see it is replacing 'MR ' from 'NAMR ' as well.

Kindly suggest a solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace whole word using ms sql server "replace"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27378945/replace-whole-word-using-ms-sql-server-replace)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace first occurrence of substring in a string in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38911588/replace-first-occurrence-of-substring-in-a-string-in-sql)

Comment: None of the above referenced posts could be considered as an answer to this question. The OP wants to substitute *every* (not just the first one) occurrence of a word, provided it is not a substring of another word.

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you using?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try the following query. Here at the start and end a space has been inserted first and then removed that space.

```
DECLARE @i VARCHAR(250)
SET @i = 'MR JOHN NAMR is working from 3 days.'

SELECT rtrim(ltrim(Replace(replace(' '+@i+' ',' MR ','  '),
' MR ','  ')))
```

The output is as shown below

> JOHN NAMR is working from 3 days.

You can find the live demo [**Demo Replace Word**](https://rextester.com/VVL68114)

Comment: Remove space for not considering removed word space. See the demo https://rextester.com/MZA81994