# Removing list of words from a string in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have table table_1 with data below:

```
| WordID| Add  |
+-------+------+
|   1   | Hello| 
|   2   | Hi   | 
|   3   | Go   |
|   4   | Come |
```

And I have a String "Hello, Please Go to John's House."

I want to remove hello and go from the string using SQL Server and output result should be

```
", Please to John's House"
```

How can I do it ?

Comment: You seem to be arbitrarily removing the comma and period, but leaving in the apostrophe.  What rules do you have for removing punctuation?  What about extra spaces when a word is removed, such as `, Please__to_John's_House.`?

Comment: Please find the edited question. I just need to remove that words from table. Others can be fine

Comment: What would happen if a word is just part of a different word? What should be the result for: `'Hello, Please Go to John''s House who left long ago.'`?

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27378945/replace-whole-word-using-ms-sql-server-replace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using a function created by Chris Morris and explained by Dwain Camps in [here](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/splitting-strings-based-on-patterns).

I changed the string to test for false positives.

```
declare @list varchar(255) = 'Hello, Please Go to Phillip''s House who left long ago.';

create table table_1(WordID int, [Add] varchar(255));
insert into table_1(WordID, [Add]) values
(1,   'Hello'), 
(2,   'Hi'), 
(3,   'Go'),
(4,   'Come');


SELECT ( SELECT Item + ''
            FROM dbo.PatternSplitCM(@list, '%[^a-zA-Z'']%') ps
            WHERE NOT EXISTS( SELECT * FROM table_1 t WHERE ps.Item = t.[Add])
            ORDER BY ItemNumber
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('./text()[1]', 'varchar(max)')
```

The function definition is here:

```
-- PatternSplitCM will split a string based on a pattern of the form 
-- supported by LIKE and PATINDEX 
-- 
-- Created by: Chris Morris 12-Oct-2012 
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[PatternSplitCM]
(
       @List                VARCHAR(8000) = NULL
       ,@Pattern            VARCHAR(50)
) RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING 
AS 
RETURN
    WITH numbers AS (
      SELECT TOP(ISNULL(DATALENGTH(@List), 0))
       n = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
      FROM
      (VALUES (0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) d (n),
      (VALUES (0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) e (n),
      (VALUES (0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) f (n),
      (VALUES (0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) g (n))
    SELECT
      ItemNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY MIN(n)),
      Item = SUBSTRING(@List,MIN(n),1+MAX(n)-MIN(n)),
      [Matched]
     FROM (
      SELECT n, y.[Matched], Grouper = n - ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY y.[Matched],n)
      FROM numbers
      CROSS APPLY (
          SELECT [Matched] = CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(@List,n,1) LIKE @Pattern THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
      ) y
     ) d
     GROUP BY [Matched], Grouper;
```

Comment: Your solution is incomplete as it replaces things that shouldn't be replaced. You also used an UPDATE instead of a SELECT. Just because it works, it doesn't mean that it's correct.

Answer (score 0):

You need a (fake) update for the table:

```
declare @list varchar(255) = 'Hello, Please Go to John''s House.';

create table table_1(WordID int, [Add] varchar(255));
insert into table_1(WordID, [Add]) values
(1,   'Hello'), 
(2,   'Hi'), 
(3,   'Go'),
(4,   'Come');

update table_1
set @list = replace(@list, [Add], '');

select @list;
```

Result:

```
, Please  to John's House.
```

Comment: My first thought as well, but this is oversimplified.  For example Hillsdale would become llsdale

Comment: I know but in OP's question it is not clarified that the items in the table should be treated as full words or not. In that case Full Text Search should be involved.

Comment: I believe solution from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27378945/replace-whole-word-using-ms-sql-server-replace could be incorporated

Comment: @KamilGosciminski why did you delete your answer? It does what it is supposed to. If there are further requirements it's up to the OP to clarify.