# MS SQL Server - replace names while avoiding words containing the names

Tags: sql, sql-server, replace

This is my first time posting on Stack Overflow, so please let me know if I can do anything better or provide more information.

I have been working on this issue for a few days now. I have a table with comments from employees about the company. Some of them could refer to specific employees in the company. For HR reasons, we want to replace any occurrence of an employee name with the word 'employee'. We aren't accounting for typos or misspellings.

An example of my desired outcome would be:

```
Input: 'I dislike dijon mustard. My boss Jon sucks.'

Name to search for: 'Jon'

Output: 'I dislike dijon mustard. My boss employee sucks.'
```

Another example:

```
Input: 'Aggregating data is boring. Greg is the worst person ever.'

Name to search for: 'Greg'

Output: 'Aggregating data is boring. employee is the worst person ever.'
```

I want to search the comments for occurrences of the employee names, but *only* if they aren't followed by other letters or numbers on either end. Occurrences with spaces or punctuation on either end of the name should be replaced.

So far I have tried the suggestions in the following threads:

[How to replace a specific word in a sentence without replacing in substring in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54157844/how-to-replace-a-specific-word-in-a-sentence-without-)
replacing-in-substring-in-s

This yielded the following

```
update c
set c.Comment = rtrim(ltrim(Replace(replace(' ' + c.Comment + ' ',' ' + en.FirstName + ' ', 'employee'), ' ' + en.FirstName + ' ', 'employee')))
from AnswerComment c
join #EmployeeNames en on en.SurveyId = c.SurveyId
    and c.Comment like '%' + en.FirstName + '%'
```

However, I got results like this:

```
Input: 'I hate bob.'

Name to search for: 'Bob'

Output: 'I hate bob.'


Input: 'Jon sucks'

Name to search for: 'Jon'

Output: 'employeesucks'
```

A coworker looked at this thread [Replace whole word using ms sql server "replace"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27378945/replace-whole-word-using-ms-sql-server-replace)

and gave me the following based off of it:

```
DECLARE @token VARCHAR(10) = 'bob';
DECLARE @replaceToken VARCHAR(10) = 'employee';

DECLARE @paddedToken VARCHAR(10) = ' ' + @token + ' ';
DECLARE @paddedReplaceToken VARCHAR(10) = ' ' + @replaceToken + ' ';
;WITH Step1 AS (
    SELECT CommentorId
         , QuestionId
         , Comment
         , REPLACE(Comment, @paddedToken, @paddedReplaceToken) AS [Value]
      FROM AnswerComment
     WHERE SurveyId = 90492
       AND Comment LIKE '%' + @token + '%'
), Step2 AS (
    SELECT CommentorId
         , QuestionId
         , Comment
         , REPLACE([Value], @paddedToken, @paddedReplaceToken) AS [Value]
      FROM Step1
), Step3 AS (
    SELECT CommentorId
         , QuestionId
         , Comment
         , IIF(CHARINDEX(LTRIM(@paddedToken), [Value]) = 1, STUFF([Value], 1, LEN(TRIM(@paddedToken)), TRIM(@paddedReplaceToken)), [Value]) AS [Value]
      FROM Step2
)
SELECT CommentorId
     , QuestionId
     , Comment
     , IIF(CHARINDEX(REVERSE(RTRIM(@paddedToken)), REVERSE([Value])) = 1, 
        REVERSE(STUFF(REVERSE([Value]), CHARINDEX(REVERSE(RTRIM(@paddedToken)), REVERSE([Value])), LEN(RTRIM(@paddedToken)), REVERSE(RTRIM(@paddedReplaceToken)))), 
        [Value])
  FROM Step3;
```

But I have no idea how I would implement this.

Another thread I can't find anymore suggested using `%[^a-z0-9A-Z]%` for searching, like this:

```
update c
set c.Comment = REPLACE(c.Comment, en.FirstName, 'employee')
from AnswerComment c
join #EmployeeNames en on en.SurveyId = c.SurveyId
    and c.Comment like '%' + en.FirstName + '%'
    and c.Comment not like '%[^a-z0-9A-Z]%' + en.FirstName + '%[^a-z0-9A-Z]%'
select @@ROWCOUNT [first names replaced]
```

This doesn't work for me. It replaces occurrences of the employee names even if they're part of a larger word, like in this example:

```
Input: 'I dislike dijon mustard.'

Name to search for: 'Jon'

Output: 'I dislike diemployee mustard.'
```

At this point it seems to me that it's impossible to accomplish this. Is there anything wrong with how I've implemented these, or anything obvious that I'm missing?

Comment: doesn't this work for you?

declare @input nvarchar(max) =  'I dislike dijon mustard. My boss Jon sucks.'

-- Name to search for: 'Jon'

select replace(@input, ' Jon ', ' employee ')

Answer (score 0):

Something like this seems to work.

```
declare @charsTable table (notallowed char(1))
insert into @charsTable (notallowed) values (',')
insert into @charsTable (notallowed) values ('.')
insert into @charsTable (notallowed) values (' ')

declare @input nvarchar(max) = 'Aggregating data is boring. Greg is the worst person ever.'
declare @name nvarchar(50) = 'Greg'
--declare @input nvarchar(max) =  'I dislike dijon mustard. You know who sucks? My boss Jon.'
--declare @name nvarchar(50) = 'Jon'

select case when @name + notallowed = value or notallowed + @name = value or notallowed + @name = value then replace(value, @name, 'employee') else value end 'data()'  from string_split(@input, ' ')
left join @charsTable on @name + notallowed = value or notallowed + @name = value or notallowed + @name + notallowed = value
for xml path('')
```

Results:

> Aggregating data is boring. employee is the worst person ever.
>
> I dislike dijon mustard. You know who sucks? My boss employee.

Comment: But there can be a '.' (dot) or a ',' (comma) directly after the name of en employee!

Comment: txs @Luuk.  i thought this was much simpler than it really is.  others will probably look at splitting the string too.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method that uses a combination of STUFF and PATINDEX.

It'll only replace the first occurence of the name in the comment.
So it might have to be executed more than once till nothing gets updated by it.

```
UPDATE c
SET c.Comment = STUFF(c.Comment, PATINDEX('%[^a-z0-9]'+en.FirstName+'[^a-z0-9]%', '/'+c.Comment+'/'), len(en.FirstName), 'employee')
FROM AnswerComment c
JOIN #EmployeeNames en ON en.SurveyId = c.SurveyId
WHERE '/'+c.Comment+'/' LIKE '%[^a-z0-9]'+en.FirstName+'[^a-z0-9]%';
```